# mounting viirtualbox shared folder on debian

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian

i try mount VB shared filder (host is windows)

```
mount -t vboxsf share ~/host
/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: Protocol error
```

1) the operating systems on both host and guest machine 
Host : windows 7
Guest : debian

2) How you are sharing the folder.
i setup it on Devices/shared folders settings - virtualbox configuration. 
i setup E:/ as Tansient Folder

3) Have you installed Virtual Box Guest Additions on the guest? 
yes

4) Which version of virtual box you are using 
4.3.8

5) Have you installed the Virtual Box extension pack from their website? We need more information to be able to help.

i not install extension pack, only from menu quest additions then in virtual debian as root install it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain: 1) the operating systems on both host and guest machine 2) How you are sharing the folder. 3) Have you installed Virtual Box Guest Additions on the guest? 4) Which version of virtual box you are using 5) Have you installed the Virtual Box extension pack from their website? We need more information to be able to help.

Comment: i update informations can you help ?

Comment: Answered [elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10062105/720999) (found by Googling for `virtualbox+linux+guest+shared+folder`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, just experimented with Debian Wheezy guest on a Windows XP host (VirtualBox 4.3.8).

Prerequisites:

- Host:

  - Create a shared folder (using the UI or the `vboxmanage` command).
  - Notice that it has *both* the pathname *and* the "shortname".

    For instance, I might share the folder `C:\Documents and settings\User` making it available under the name `user`.
- Debian guest:

  - Have `virtualbox-guest-dkms` installed, compiled for the current kernel (done automatically; if not, install the matching `linux-headers` package and run `dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-guest-dkms`).
  - Have `virtualbox-guest-utils` to make `mount.vboxsf` available.

Now on your guest you can do

```
# mkdir /tmp/foo
# mount.vboxsf user /tmp/foo
```

or, alternatively, the last step can be spelled as

```
# mount -t vboxsf user /tmp/foo
```

*Notice the usage of the short name* for the "device" argument in the call to `mount`.

The answer is based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14937377/720999) in the thread dealing with the similar issue elsewhere on SO.

Answer (score 0):

The below is based on [this](http://virtualboxes.org/doc/installing-guest-additions-on-debian/), [this](https://github.com/icy/pacapt), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73059/how-to-copy-paste-from-ubuntu-virtualbox-guest-to-windows-host), and [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=149305), with my additions:

1. Login as root (or use sudo)
2. Update your APT database with `apt-get update`
3. Install the latest security updates with `apt-get upgrade`
4. Install required packages with `apt-get install build-essential module-assistant`
5. Configure your system for building kernel modules by running `m-a prepare`
6. Click on `Install Guest Additions…` from the *Devices menu,* then run `mount /media/cdrom`
7. Go to VirtualMachine's `Settings->General->Advanced->Shared Clipboard (Bidirectional)` and `Settings->General->Advanced->Drag'n'Drop (Bidirectional)`
8. Run `sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run,`
9. Install pacapt as pacman: 
   `wget -O /usr/local/bin/pacapt  https://github.com/icy/pacapt/raw/ng/pacapt`
   `chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/pacapt`
   `ln -sv /usr/local/bin/pacapt /usr/local/bin/pacman || true`
10. Install other required packages (answer `Y` when asked *`Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version)`*:
     `for i in virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-additions virtualbox-modules virtualbox-host-modules virtualbox-source virtualbox-host-source; do echo $i ; pacman -S $i ; echo "------------" ; done`
11. Append `vboxsf` to */etc/modules*
12. Run `modprobe vboxsf`
13. Check success with: `mount -t vboxsf tmp ~/shared/tmp/` (assuming your shared folder is defined as below)
    *Note:* if you get a `/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such file or directory` or similar, it means you didn't create the mount point sub-directory.

[image: shared folders]

[image: ~/shared/tmp]

[image: VBoxGuestEditions.ISO]